# Is there a way to set permissions so a process could use a specific device?

Tags: systemd, session, logind

As you can read, for instance [here](http://enotty.pipebreaker.pl/2012/05/23/linux-automatic-user-acl-management/), logind, which is a part of systemd, can set permissions to some devices for user sessions. [There's also a vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcD4Qr5ldbI) showing how this kind of behavior works in practice. In short, if you start, let's say, amarok, and you play some song, you will hear the sound till you switch to another user or TTY where you have only the login prompt. That's because the active session became inactive.

I know that you can simply add a user (or users) to a specific group, in this case "audio", and that will 'fix' this issue, but I'm wondering if there's another solution. What I really want is to set some permissions for the process so it could use the sound card all the time, even when all users have their sessions locked.

Is that possible? I'm asking because I often listen to the music and I don't really need my monitor to be on most of the time, so I just lock the screen. But when I lock the screen, the active session becomes inactive and amarok stops playing. And yes, the screen should be locked, and not just turned off.

**EDIT:**

I don't think that it matters which distro I'm using because if there's systemd on board, it would be the exact same issue. Anyways, I'm using debian sid, but some packages like systemd, udev (and some dependencies) are from experimental branch, and now it's the 219-9 version.

Comment: Possibly running `nohup program_x & ; disown` could help. Or using [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)

Comment: But the process works just fine. When I lock the screen, it can't use the sound card anymore, at least till I unlock the screen.

Comment: Have you tried using `loginctl enable-linger` for the account?

Comment: According to the arch wiki: `The systemd user instance is started after the first login of a user and killed after the last session of the user is closed. Sometimes it may be useful to start it right after boot, and keep the systemd user instance running after the last session closes, for instance to have some user process running without any open session. Lingering is used to that effect.` That doesn't concern an inactive user session because `systemd --user` is present all the time.

Comment: I routinely leave my music playing on my Fedora 21 laptop while I sleep after having locked it. So I don't think locking your computer screen should mark a session as inactive just because of systemd.

Comment: Do you use the gnome desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulseaudio is started via xdg autostart, which can be found under `~/.config/autostart/` . There's a file called `pulseaudio.desktop`, and in that file I've changed the default `exec` line to this one:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/sg audio -c "pulseaudio -D"
```

When I log in to the system, the pulseaudio process looks like this:

```
$ ps -eo user,group,args | grep pulse
morfik   audio    pulseaudio -D
morfik   audio    /usr/lib/pulseaudio/pulse/gconf-helper
```

And now I'm able to listen to the music all the time. I think this is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, which version/flavor of Linux you are using, but looks like ACL's for sound devices are controlled by ConsoleKit via udev rules. On my Debian host, I see something like below in /lib/udev/rules.d/70-udev-acl.rules

```
# sound devices
SUBSYSTEM=="sound", TAG+="udev-acl"
```

I would play with untagging this, so consolekit won't add sound devices into its database and not manage ACL on sound devices

Comment: I verified on my desktop with commenting above line and after reboot. No more ACL management for sound devices and I can play songs with my screen locked

Comment: I updated the question. Now, consolekit is obsolete stuff -- you can read more about it here http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ConsoleKit/ , and my system doesn't use it. Logind is a replacement for it, and it does basically the same thing. I tried to comment out the line you gave me, and after reboot, my system doesn't see any sound cards. Even if it did and this worked just fine, I don't think that I would use this solution -- it's because It would be the same thing as adding a user to the audio group, at least I see it in this way.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at logind details and yes, it's doing similar stuff. That is looking for udev TAG 'uaccess' to identify devices to manage and it's in /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules. It's all coming down to basic unix permissions, in my opinion you have these options 1) remove sound card tag via udev, so logind doesn't manage audio device and locking screen,switching users - won't change permissions of sound devices. you could set perms as you like  2) you could simply find amarok binary and set it's group to be audio and setgid it, so it's effective group becomes audio

Comment: I checked the second solution, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I set `audio group` to the amarok binary, and the permissions are as follows: `-rwxr-sr-x`, but when I try to start amarok as a regular user, I get this error: `QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave. unnamed app(24333): KUniqueApplication: Cannot find the D-Bus session server:  "Unable to autolaunch when setuid"`

Comment: hmm, looks like running setuid programs in GUI seems way complicated and blocked for security reasons for ex: http://www.gtk.org/setuid.html. I'll research more and let you know, this is good stuff - learning new things !

Comment: btw, I am able to verify solution 1 listed above and it works fine. You do not see any soundcards after removing tag is because, you don't have any perms to /dev/snd* (not managed anymore by logind). To fix, I just gave myself perms, adding myself via setfacl to /dev/snd* .. and now sound devices are 'out' from systemd-logind and sound works for whoever has ACL's set

Comment: The same behavior can be achieved by adding specific users to the audio group (without changing anything). :) I just want a single process to have access to these audio devices if it's even possible, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: Not sure, if you are still looking for any alternatives, but text/curses based mp3 players seem not effected by this issue (for ex: mpg321) - if that's an option for you. As far as running setuid/gid apps in GUI, it seems not possible out-of-box, but needs some helper apps, found some reference here http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/system-activation.txt (though couldn't find way to setgid)

Answer (score 0):

Let me say I know little about audio on Linux desktop. Mea Culpa if this won't help.

I would set the group-permissions of the audio device:

```
chgrp audio <dev-path>
chmod g+rw <dev-path>
```

to the group that amarok runs in. Use systemd to force amarok to run in that group. First copy the amarok systemd file to /etc/systemd/user/ and modify it:

```
[Service]
Group=audio
```

(that's a modification, not the entire file).

But there may be a more "sophisticated" answer due to the multiple layers that are today's Linux-audio system.

Comment: As for `chgrp audio` -- all devices under /dev/snd/ already have the `audio` group, but this shouldn't matter when you use pulseaudio, and that's the case. When it comes to systemd's service, I tried it, but I got the following error: `Failed at step GROUP spawning /usr/bin/amarok: Operation not permitted. amarok.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP`, and I don't think that I can change these groups as a regular user. I have other service that requires group change, but it's a normal system daemon, and it works just fine.

`

Comment: The Amarok service isn't started by root? It's possible Amarok needs other group permissions for other puproses. Too bad it isn't that easy.

Comment: It's just a music player. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about running the player in vnc framebuffer?  In Mint 17...

```
# apt search vfb
p   xvfb                            - Virtual Framebuffer 'fake' X server
p   xvfb:i386                       - Virtual Framebuffer 'fake' X server
```

You would use VNC to view the desktop as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb

Comment: I've read the `Usage scenarios` in the wiki link, and I don't think any of those apply here. The process (amarok) just need some permissions, and I have no idea how to set them, if that's even possible.

Comment: What permissions do you think you need?  I highly doubt systemd is changing the permissions on devices just because you switch tty's and if it does i'm going to do my best to avoid it like the plague from now on.  I don't know that this will help you either, i didn't test it, but it's the only idea i have that has a chance at working.  Also, users have permissions, not processes.

Comment: Just read the first link in the question.